# How to avoid a loop to calculate competition index

Tags: r, loops

I've to calculate so called competition index for a couple of the experiments. I have known position of the object and its size. I'd like to calculate the sum of the sizes in a certain radius and the sum of the distances to the objects that are within this radius. The example of the data are here:

```
set.seed(13181938)
    df <- data.frame(exp = rep(LETTERS[1:20], each = 100), x = rnorm(1000, 100, 50), 
                     y = rnorm(1000, 100, 50), di = rnorm(5, 2, 2))
df$comp1 <- 0
df$dist <- 0
```

I used a loop for calculations but it takes a lot of time to complete the calculation for 1000 objects. In the real data set I have more than 10000 objects.

```
fori <- function(x) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
    for (j in 1:nrow(x)){
      dist = sqrt((x$x[j] - x$x[i])^2 + (x$y[j] - x$y[i])^2)
        #print(paste(x$exp[i], x$exp[j], dist))
        if(dist < 2 & x$exp[i] == x$exp[j]){
        x$comp1[i] = x$comp1[i] + x$di[j]
        x$dist[i] = x$dist[i] + dist
      }
    }
  }
  df <- data.frame(x)
  return(df)
}

abc <- fori(df)
```

It takes a very long time to run this loop for the example and it means that it will take much more for the entire data set. Can you suggest any other way? I tried `apply` and `DT` but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loops like this are a perfect candidate for speeding up with Rcpp. The logic translates across unchanged:

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('
List
computeIndex(const NumericVector x,
             const NumericVector y, 
             const NumericVector di,
             const CharacterVector ex)
{
    int n = x.size();
    NumericVector comp1(n), dist(n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            double dx = x[j] - x[i], dy = y[j] - y[i];
            double d = std::sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

            if((d < 2) && (ex[i] == ex[j]))
            {
                comp1[i] += di[j];
                dist[i] +=  d;
            }
        }
    }

    return List::create(Named("comp1") = comp1,
                        Named("dist") = dist);
}
')

res <- data.frame(computeIndex(df$x, df$y, df$di, df$exp))
```

Not only is this faster than the equivalent R-only code, but it avoids having to 
allocate any O(N^2) objects. You can also combine this with dplyr to avoid needless comparisons between rows with different `exp` values:

```
df %>%
    group_by(exp) %>%
    do({
        res <- computeIndex(.$x, .$y, .$di, .$exp)
        data.frame(., res)
    })
```

Comment: I got en error: Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.

Comment: try it now; `cppFunction` does a `using namespace Rcpp`

Comment: C:/RBuildTools/3.4/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I###########/R/win-library/3.3/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/mali/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgJBdiN/sourceCpp-i386-w64-mingw32-0.12.6"  -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c file4b43ae7ed8.cpp -o file4b43ae7ed8.o
file4b43ae7ed8.cpp: In function 'Rcpp::List computeIndex(Rcpp::NumericVector, Rcpp::NumericVector, Rcpp::NumericVector, Rcpp::CharacterVector)': file4b43ae7ed8.cpp:31:46: error: 'named' was not declared in this scope   return List::create(named("comp1") = comp1,

Comment: file4b43ae7ed8.cpp:33:13: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
             }
             ^
make: *** [file4b43ae7ed8.o] Error 1
Warning message:
running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="sourceCpp_8.dll" OBJECTS="file4b43ae7ed8.o"' had status 2 
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.

Comment: do not understand that

Comment: That should be `Named`, not `named` in the return statement. Try it now.

Comment: Works fine, can you briefly explain what is that? Is this a bridge between c++ and R???

Comment: Yes, that's basically what Rcpp does: let you embed C++ code very easily inside R. The code gets compiled into a temporary dll, which is then loaded into your R session. Have a look at the website, at [rcpp.org](http://www.rcpp.org).

Answer (score 1):

I use `dplyr` and a join on `exp`. Then `summarise` for each (generated) id.

```
res <- df %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  merge(df, by='exp') %>% 
  mutate(dist = sqrt((x.x - x.y)^2 + (y.x - y.y)^2)) %>% 
  filter(dist < 2 ) %>%
  group_by(id,x.x,y.x,di.x) %>%
  summarise(comp1 = sum(di.y),
                      dist = sum(dist))
```

results in :

```
Source: local data frame [2,000 x 6]
Groups: id, x.x, y.x [?]

      id       x.x       y.x       di.x      comp1     dist
   <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
1      1 127.36166  89.64637 -0.2508979 -0.2508979 0.000000
2      2  90.98491 153.17911  1.4561061  1.4561061 0.000000
3      3  58.96620 144.72710  2.7909274  2.7909274 0.000000
4      4 162.44443 132.35379  3.0175213  3.0175213 0.000000
5      5 184.52673  47.12997  1.1127618  1.1127618 0.000000
6      6  57.07334 126.03554 -0.2508979 -0.2508979 0.000000
7      7  22.28946 110.69319  1.4561061  2.5688679 1.267998
8      8  40.54007 123.32645  2.7909274  2.7909274 0.000000
9      9 179.37667  61.45213  3.0175213  3.0175213 0.000000
10    10  73.82714  67.86194  1.1127618  1.1127618 0.000000
# ... with 1,990 more rows
```

PS: looking at the criterium `if(dist < 2 & x$exp[i] == x$exp[j])` means only a few rows match the criterium of dist < 2.

Comment: Thx, the second part works fine as long as I analyzed it. I will come back with questions if it will be needed.

Comment: I was struggling a bit to get the right calculation in. That is why the answer changed so much. The solution now works very smooth.