# R alternatives to looping for more than 10 million data

Tags: r

Need some solution for a optimized code for running a loop without using indexing

```
  abc <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,4,5) , 
                    B = c("A","B","C","D","E") , 
                    C = c("A1" ,"B1" , "A1" , "C1" , "A1") )
```

Lets say ,I want to add a new column say D. if and only if C=="A1"  and A > 2 then D will be 1.
so my output need to be :

```
  A B C  D  
1 1 A A1 NA
2 2 B B1 NA
3 3 C A1 1
4 4 D C1 NA 
5 5 E A1 1
```

It can be done as :

```
     for (i in 1:nrow(abc){
         if(abc$C[i] == "A1" & abc$A[i] > 2 )
          {
              abc$D[i] == 1
           }
          }
```

But I expect the code without using indexing for faster processing

When I tried only if :

```
     if(abc$C == "A1" & abc$A > 2 )
        {
            abc$D == 1
        }
```

This code gives error (only first row is checked)

Then I tried dplyr (mutate). It worked

```
     abc <- abc %>% mutate( D = ifelse(C == "A1" & A > 2 , 1,NA))
```

But the problem is when I use function to do this. Suppose I have a function

```
     test <- function(abc ,abc$A , abc$C){
        
            abc <- abc %>% mutate( D = 1)
        
                return(abc)
        }
```

Now I want to use this function to create D and before calling this
function I have to check the condition for C and A

So I tried the solution as:
This is not working.

```
abc <- abc %>% mutate( if(C == "A1" & A > 2) ) %>% test(abc ,abc$A , abc$C)
```

I need solution to tackle this type of Scenario Not like this

```
for (i in 1:nrow(abc){
if(abc$C[i] == "A1" & abc$A[i] > 2 )
{
  abc <- test(abc ,abc$A , abc$C)
} 
}
```

Need a better suggestion. Please execute the code and tell me a better way.
I have 20 million data. so Indexing would
Take lot of time (I think)

Comment: written from scratch, didn't check if works fine `abc$D <- apply(abc, 1, function(x) ifelse(x[3] == 'A1' & x[1] > 2, 1, NA))`

Comment: In your expected output, C in row 4 is not "A1"

Comment: Generally it's very easy using an index as in `idx <- abc$C == "A1" & abc$A > 2` and then `abc$D[idx] <- 1`

Comment: I do not have any particular solution but for me using Rcpp package helped a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020341/how-to-avoid-a-loop-to-calculate-competition-index. I worked with big dataset and it decresed the time of looping to few seconds

Comment: Thanks Adamm ,  docendo discimus ,  Mateusz1981 for the support. I have updated the post. I am looking for some workaround using mutate. My main focus is to use the function test. i.e. test will be called and new column will be created only when the condition is met. so the calling process to test should happen on the satisfaction of condition. if condition did not satisfy the function should not be invoked and next iteration should start

Answer (score 4):

You should use data.table framework to make it faster:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(abc)
abc[C == "A1" & A > 2, D := 1]
```

Comment: You are right, But what I want is to use a function which returns the same dataframe adding some extra columns when the condition is satisfied.

Comment: I think you asked an XY question. Can you ask what it is realy your problem?

Comment: Thanks  Emmanuel-Lin for the support. I have updated the post. I am looking for some workaround using mutate. My main focus is to use the function test. i.e. test will be called and new column will be created only when the condition is met. so the calling process to test should happen on the satisfaction of condition. if condition did not satisfy the function should not be invoked and next iteration should start

Answer (score 2):

The fastest of the 3 solutions proposed are `data.table` and the index vector (docendo discimus) then `dplyr`.

```
f <- function(DF){
    DF %>% mutate(D = ifelse(C == "A1" & A > 2 , 1,NA))
}

g <- function(DF){
    setDT(DF)
    DF[C == "A1" & A > 2, D := 1]
}

h <- function(DF){
    idx <- DF[["C"]] == "A1" & DF[["A"]] > 2
    DF[["D"]][idx] <- 1
    DF
}

set.seed(3472)
n <- 20e6
abcd <- data.frame(
    A = sample(5, n, TRUE),
    B = sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"), n, TRUE),
    C = sample(c("A1", "B1", "A1", "C1", "A1"), n, TRUE)
)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    dplyr = {f(abcd)},
    data.table = {g(abcd)},
    index = {h(abcd)},
    times = 10)
Unit: seconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
      dplyr 5.193977 5.230753 5.299558 5.293965 5.356213 5.419657    10
 data.table 1.880420 1.929242 1.976511 1.980238 2.021672 2.089020    10
      index 1.866140 1.918988 1.979210 1.956200 2.053038 2.153510    10
```

Note that in the `data.table` based solution, function `setDT()` is called repeatedly, when in a real case use it would be called just once.
In favour of the index vector solution, it uses base R only with no need to load an external package.

Comment: Thanks Rui Barradas for the support.Your code is a great way of doing it.  I have updated the post. I am looking for some workaround using mutate.Because I am using SparklyR with hive which doesnot support much of indexing(as per my knowledge) My main focus is to use the function test. i.e. test will be called and new column will be created only when the condition is met. so the calling process to test should happen on the satisfaction of condition. if condition did not satisfy the function should not be invoked and next iteration should start. As I have many other conditions and new columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your `dplyr` solution is correct by itself

```
abc <- abc %>% mutate( D = ifelse(C == "A1" & A > 2 , 1,NA))
```

You don't need need a follow up function to check conditions, this is done inside the `ifelse`

If you really want to pipe the result to another function, you need to remove `abc` as the first function argument as this is implicit after `%>%`.

```
... %>% test(abc, arg2, arg3, ...)
```

should be

```
... %>% test(arg2, arg3, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ronomal.

Answer (score 0):

we can pass the column names in function as:

```
abc <- function_name(rlang::sym('column_name1'),rlang::sym('column_name2'))

function_name<- function( var1 , var2)
   {
      abc <- abc %>% 
      mutate( C = !!var1,
              A = !!var2)

#now everytime we call the function with specific column names the function 
#will refer to those column and iterate the values of the column to check 
#for any given conditions

abc <- abc %>% 
         mutate( new_col_D = ifelse(C == "A1" & A > 2 , 1,NA)))  

       abc <- abc %>% select(-A,-C)

       return(abc)        

    }
```